# Why is my submenu parent focusing when I hover over another menu item?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, submenu

I'm working on a side navigation menu for my website using a bootstrap template. I'm a designer, not a developer, but I'm trying to learn by doing. I got everything working right, mostly. But I can't figure out why when I hover over the first or second menu items, the third one is expanded.

It's a parent for a submenu, but I've tried removing CSS rules one by one to see if that changes or fixes anything, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is a link to the codepen that has bootstrap already loaded.

https://codepen.io/steve-mullen/pen/WNgNBjE

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <header id="header" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar nav-menu">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="no-sub-nav"><a href="#home" class="scrollto active">1<span>Menu 1</span></a></li>
        <li class="no-sub-nav"><a href="#about" class="scrollto">2<span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-sub-nav"><a href="#portfolio" class="scrollto">3<span>Menu 3</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href=""><span>Sub 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Sub 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Sub 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Sub 4</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #272829;
}

a {
  color: #0563bb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #067ded;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9997;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #header {
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e9ec;
    left: -300px;
  }
}

/* Main Nav */

.nav-menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


.nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.no-sub-nav a,
.no-sub-nav a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(26,26,26,1.00);
  padding: 10px 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu a {
    border: 4px #1a1a1a solid;
}

.nav-menu a i,
.nav-menu a:focus i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-menu a span,
.nav-menu a:focus span {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}


@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .nav-menu a,
  .nav-menu a:focus {
    width: 56px;
  }
    
  .nav-menu a span,
  .nav-menu a:focus span {
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
    
    .nav-menu li {
        padding: 0;
    }

  .sub-nav {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .has-sub-nav:hover .sub-nav {
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3 sec;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left:15px;
  }

}   

.nav-menu a:hover,
.nav-menu .active,
.nav-menu .active:focus,
.nav-menu:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border: 4px white solid;
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-menu a:hover span,
.nav-menu .active span,
.nav-menu .active:focus span,
.nav-menu:hover>a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.no-sub-nav a:hover, 
.no-sub-nav:hover>a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-sub-nav a:hover span,
.no-sub-nav:hover>a span{
  display: block;
}


/* Sub Nav */
.has-sub-nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.has-sub-nav * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.has-sub-nav ul {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.no-sub-nav {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.has-sub-nav li {
  padding-bottom:8px;
}

.has-sub-nav a,
.has-sub-nav a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(26,26,26,1.00);
  padding: 10px 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #f2f3f5;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-sub-nav a {
    border: 4px #1a1a1a solid;
}

.has-sub-nav a span,
.has-sub-nav a:focus span {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.has-sub-nav a:hover,
.has-sub-nav .active,
.has-sub-nav .active:focus,
.has-sub-nav:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border: 4px white solid;
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.has-sub-nav a:hover span,
.has-sub-nav .active span,
.has-sub-nav .active:focus span,
.has-sub-nav:hover>a span {
  color: #fff;
}

.has-sub-nav a:hover,
.has-sub-nav:hover>a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.has-sub-nav a:hover span,
.has-sub-nav:hover>a span{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue in your CSS, you just need to remove the `width: 100%` in

```
.has-sub-nav a,
.has-sub-nav a:focus
```

and it will works as normal.

This is because the `width:100%` make the 3rd menu to fit to its container's(`ul`) width, so whenenver 1st or 2nd menu is expanding, `ul` is expanding and cause 3rd to following its parent width then cause the issue.

https://codepen.io/zeikman/pen/dyqPZKW